# Submit button of the form in flask is not working

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

Submit button of the form is not working. After submitting the form,it should redirect to the next page but nothing is happening. On submit, it was supposed to redirect to the link localhost:5000/dashboard-data and then print the data on the  web page. Please if anybody could help me. I have provided as much details as I could.

This is dashboard.py

```
import os
import random
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template , request
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
PEOPLE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PEOPLE_FOLDER

data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Projects\\api\\Tweet_qlik_first.xlsx')
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    if request.method=='GET':
        matplotlib.use('Agg')
        data.to_sql('users', con=engine)
        topic_list=engine.execute("SELECT distinct Topic FROM users").fetchall()
        count=engine.execute('''Select Topic,count(*) from users group by Topic''',).fetchall()
        print(count)
        x = []
        y = []
        for tr in count:
            x.append(tr[0])
            y.append(tr[1])
        plt.bar(x,y)

        plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)

        plt.xlabel('Topics')
        plt.ylabel('Tweet Count')
        ax = plt.gca()
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')

        plt.tight_layout()
        x=random.randint(0,9999999)
        img_name='plot'+str(x)+'.png'
        plt.savefig('static/'+img_name)

        full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], img_name)
        tl=[]
        for tr in topic_list:
            tl.append(tr[0])
        return render_template("main.html",topics=tl,img=full_filename)
@app.route('/dashboard-data',methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():

    if request.method=='POST':
        result=request.form["topic_list"]
        topic_fcount=engine.execute('''Select Topic,"Follower Count" from users where Topic=?''',(str(result),)).fetchall()
        return render_template("dashboard.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "/dashboard-data" method = 'POST'>
Topic
<select name="topic_list">

{% for each in topics %}

<option value="{{each}}" selected="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>

{% endfor %}

</select>

<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>

<img src="{{ img }}" alt="User Image" >
</html>
```

This is dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for row in topic_fcount %}
{{row}}
{%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Submit button of the form is not working. After submitting the form,it should redirect to the next page but nothing is happening.

Try changing the button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your button as a button, not as a submit.
You just need to edit your button from

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

to

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

and you will have success.